# Unable to start eclipse even after changing the config.ini file

Tags: java, android, eclipse, configuration

I have been having trouble starting eclipse since this morning. I have had a look at log files and made changes to config.ini file manually by referring to some solutions provided by StackOverflow, but had no luck.

Here is my config.ini file

```
#This configuration file was written by:org.eclipse.equinox.internal.frameworkadmin.equinox.EquinoxFwConfigFileParser
```

#Fri Dec 06 17:08:13 WST 2013

```
equinox.use.ds=true
eclipse.buildId=M20130204-1200
osgi.bundles=reference\:file\:org.eclipse.equinox.simpleconfigurator_1.0.301.v20120914-  163612.jar@1\:start
org.eclipse.equinox.simpleconfigurator.configUrl=file\:org.eclipse.equinox.simpleconfigurat or/bundles.info
eclipse.product=com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.package.product
osgi.splashPath=platform\:/base/plugins/com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.package
osgi.framework.extensions=
osgi.bundles.defaultStartLevel=4
eclipse.application=org.eclipse.ui.ide.workbench
eclipse.p2.data.area=@config.dir/../p2/
osgi.bundles=org.eclipse.equinox.common@2:start,org.eclipse.update.configurator@3:start,org.eclipse.core.runtime@start
```

Please help me solve this problem.

Comment: goto cmd and type clean eclipse.exe

Comment: @raj clean is not a recognised internal/external command.

Comment: first go to eclipse directory in command prompt and run  clean eclipse.exe

Comment: sorry command is eclipse.exe -clean

Comment: Gives a dialog box stating error occurred and it is written in a log file

Comment: In the log file..one of the line says... org.osgi.framework.BundleException: The bundle "org.eclipse.core.runtime_3.8.0.v20120912-155025 [3]" could not be resolved. Reason: Missing Constraint: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.core.jobs; bundle-version="[3.2.0,4.0.0)"

Comment: have you installed any new software yesterday like jdk or jre or any new softwr related to eclipse

Comment: yes I did install a sample sdk for something..I might have accidentally deleted some file or overwritten it. How can I recover from it?